# Polar & rectangular forms of complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I dont understand why is a=0 and b=14. Can anyone explain?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Note that $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$.

Comment: My bad. thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to study the Unit Circle more.

$cos(\frac {\pi}2)$ = 0.

You are thinking of $\theta = \frac{\pi}4,$ for which we have $cos(\frac{\pi}4) = \frac {\sqrt{2}}2$.